# "Conservative Fields" in Inifinite Dimesions

Tags: analysis

Let $X$ be a infinite dimensional Banach space and $X^\star$ its dual. Let $f:X\rightarrow X^\star$ be a continuous function. What is a necessary and sufficient condition to find $F:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $$F'(x)=f(x)$$ where $F'$ is the derivative of $F$.

Note: In Banach spces with finite dimension we have the notion of "conservative field". What I am asking here is the analogous in infinite dimesion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A classical [theorem of Rockafellar](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-33/issue-1/On-the-maximal-monotonicity-of-subdifferential-mappings/pjm/1102977253.full) characterizes the gradients of **convex** functions.

> Theorem B. Let $T:E\to E^*$ be a multivalued mapping. In order that
> there exist a lower semicontίnuous proper convex function $f$ on $E$
> such that $T=\partial f$, it is necessary and sufficient that $T$ be a
> maximal cyclically monotone operator. Moreover, in this case $T$
> determines $f$ uniquely up to an additive constant.

Since your $f$ is continuous, you can ignore "multivalued" and "maximal". As a corollary, if $f$ can be written as the difference of two cyclically monotone maps then it is the gradient (of the difference of two corresponding functions). A function that can be written as the difference of two convex functions is called delta-convex (or d.c.). This is a pretty large class; in finite dimensions in includes all $C^2$ functions. There is a fair amount of recent literature on d.c. functions, but I don't remember seeing any better characterization of their gradients.

Comment: Thank you Pavel, I really appreciate your efforts to solve my problems.

Comment: Thank you @Tomás for posing interesting problems. :) But you did not have to accept my answer; there's at least a chance someone knows something about non-convex case.